# How to make the event sound from share button louder?

Tags: ps4

I have a little problem finding something in the settings. I want to make the event sound louder when I take a screenshot over the share button since I can barely hear it.

Is it possible to adjust the volume on this event sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no setting for that.

Comment: That's too bad. That explains why I didn't find anything during my search.

Comment: @nobody - what you could potentially do is lower the in-game volume (if the game you're playing allows that). Then, turn your TV up.